# Adding controls conditionally

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am currently working on this big project (a GUI to control hardware) that was written in C# with .NET 3.5. Now the next revision of hardware will be coming, and some of the changes are such that some of the controls that we had before are not needed, and some new controls need to be added too. Since the changes are huge, it would require almost a month to go through every control and put a condition to make it visible or not.

I was wondering if there is any other way to tackle this problem easily other than manually conditioning the whole project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the types of conditions considered when determining if a control should be visible or not?

Comment: SO far for the previous projects I did using enum, like I set the enum variant at the beginning at the startup and load controls based on it. Thanks.

Comment: So if you define the controls somehow using an `enum` it works? Bottom line is you'll somehow need to be able to tell your program whether a specific control should be rendered. Whether that is through an `enum`, tag value, or whatever; you'll need some way to identify that a specific control should be visible (or even created). Unless you switch to WPF, I can't think of a way to do this with the Framework or any existing libraries.

Comment: Thanks Babcock. I have an idea of using tag now. I will try with the tag. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make the decision to make visible or invisible based on some attribute of the control, such as its name, or tag, you could write a method that could walk a window's controls, and programmatically hide the ones you wanted hidden. For controls like a label you might key on the text of the label.

Written correctly the method could be written so that it is re-entrant so that for controls that contain other controls, the method would call itself for each of the current controls children.

The hardest part about this would be to determine how to decide programmatically make the on or off decision.

If that's not possible, another solution might be to write a small app that would read the code and list the controls you want to examine, allowing you to make a decision based on your knowledge of the application. The app then could make the changes necessary to set an attribute on the control in code so that its hidden when the code is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You usually have to design for these kinds of things, and by the sounds of it, it isn't designed for this.

but quite often, this kind changes appears quite large, but often isn't THAT big of a deal.

Comment: True, normally we used to have smaller projects and manually changing wasn't hard. But this one bit bigger and actually I wasn't the one who designed the architecture I joined later after the person left and trying to see how to change without more man hours into it. Thanks.

Comment: I find, if things can be found by a search, and you have to change each one.... even if there are hundreds, often the actual time to do that is a day or two, if that.   Sometimes if you are real clever, you can automate the replacement.